# Unity can't find my reference of an Input field

Tags: reference, input-field

**I am pretty new to Unity and game development so sorry if this is a stupid mistake.**

I am trying to create a UI in which you enter text into a input field (TMP), the script will check the input and if it reads "password", a Debug.Log is shown in the console.
I have looked around online for any help with this but nothing seems to work.
I have got a script that I assume to work, but I am getting one major problem: On line 15 it cant find the Input Field that I am trying to reference?

The script is attached to the Input Field, I am trying to reference it from there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated... Thanks!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CheckPassword : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public InputField inputField;

    public void Awake()
    {
        inputField = GetComponent<InputField>();
    }

    public void CheckInputField()
    {
        if (inputField.text == "password")
        {
            Debug.Log("Password Correct");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that due to the fact that I was using a Text Mesh Pro Input Field I had to specify that in the variable.

Instead I used: [SerializeField] TMPro.TMP_InputField inputField;

And the awake function was not necessary either.